# Using SQL and PHP to Populate a HTML Select form

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

So I am currently having some difficulty using PHP to populate a select option on an HTML form. I need to have the select options filled with the data from my sql table and then I need to populate the selections into a different table in sql. First I will desribe the sql table that I am using. This is my first time using PHP and SQL so please keep that in mind if the code is completely off.

*Note, I am able to connect to my database without any issues*

SQL Data: 
Table Name = "All Animals"
Column Name = "Group"

PHP Code:

```
$query = "SELECT *, dbo.All Animal.Group as allAnimal_Group
            LEFT JOIN dbo.All Animal on dbo.Response.animalGroup = dbo.All Animal.Group
            WHERE dbo.Response.animalGroup = %s";
    $db->query($query, $Group);
    $r = $db->fetch();
```

HTML and PHP Code:

```
                       <p>
                              <label for="animalGroup">Type</label>
                              <select name="Group" id="Group">
                                <option>Select a type:</option></select></p>
    <?php
    foreach($Group as $m)
    {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $m['Group'];?>"><?php echo $m['animalGroup'];?></option>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Thank you for looking and helping, I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: try adding backticks (`) around you table name All Animal

Comment: Table names or columns with spaces need to have backticks around them as @Fredd said, e.g. All Animals = `\`All Animals\``

Comment: Also reconsider tables with spaces in the name.

Comment: You also dont seem to use FROM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drop down list is closed before the php code. So edit it as below first.

```
<p>
                              <label for="animalGroup">Type</label>
                              <select name="Group" id="Group">
                                <option>Select a type:</option>
    <?php
    foreach($Group as $m)
    {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $m['Group'];?>"><?php echo $m['animalGroup'];?></option>
    <?php
    }
?>
</select></p>
```

For the second part of your question, put this code inside html form and submit it to the server once the selection is made. So the complete code will be

```
  <p>
<form action="your_file_name.php" method="post">

                                      <label for="animalGroup">Type</label>
                                      <select name="Group" id="Group">
                                        <option>Select a type:</option>
            <?php
            foreach($Group as $m)
            {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $m['Group'];?>"><?php echo $m['animalGroup'];?></option>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
        </select>
<input type="submit" name="submitBttn" value="Submit">
</form></p>
```

in your_file_name.php file, write this to retrieve what is selected as,

```
$_POST['Group']
```

Then you can write sql code like `"INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ($_POST['Group'])"`

More on html forms read this... http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! I updated my code as follows but I am still not having any data show up in my drop down option. $query = "SELECT *, dbo.'All Animals'.Group as allAnimal_Group
     FROM dbo.'All Animals'
     LEFT JOIN dbo.'All Animals' on dbo.Response.animalGroup = dbo.'All Animals'.Group
   WHERE dbo.Response.animalGroup = %s";
    $db->query($query, $Group);
    $r = $db->fetch();

Comment: <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="details.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">  <p>
                          <label for="allAnimal_Group">Type</label>
                          <select name="Group" id="Group">
                            <option>Select a type:</option></p>
<?php
foreach($Group as $m)
{
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $m['Group'];?>"><?php echo $m['allAnimal_Group'];?></option>
<?php
}
?></select>

Answer (score 0):

Update your query to use LIKE instead of = sign for wild character matching

```
$query = "SELECT *, dbo.'All Animals'.Group as allAnimal_Group
            FROM dbo.'All Animals'
            LEFT JOIN dbo.'All Animals' on dbo.Response.animalGroup = dbo.'All Animals'.Group
            WHERE dbo.Response.animalGroup LIKE '%s'";
```

P.S You should change the foreach to use **$r** as iterator because you are storing database result in $r and not in **$Group**

```
foreach($r as $m){
}
```